# Reverse tethering without rooting or third-party software

Tags: reverse-tether

The option "USB Internet" can be found by default in the settings of some Androids, allowing to reverse tether.

How could one know that the option does exist and work before buying a device ? 
Does it depend on the Android version only ? or the manufacturer ? both ?

Comment: That must be a manufacturer specific and device specific thing. Stock Android doesn't provide such feature (though not complicated to implement).

Comment: could you provide more details/sources about "not complicated to implement" ? I've read somewhere that it requires a piece of hardware in the smartphone, but I'm not sure about that, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: If direct tethering works on your device, all that it needs to setup reverse tethering is a few network routes on PC and Android. On Android it can be added using some VPN-based app (non-root) or manually using `ip` command (requires root). I'm not sure what kind of source you need. A web search on "reverse tethering" returns a lot of information. You can provide the link to source asking for special hardware, to make your question clear.